# Remove a MovieClip located inside another MovieClip using AS from stage

Tags: actionscript-3, flash-cs5

I have two movieclips.

First movieclip is on the stage with an instance name: main

Second movieclip is inside the first movieclip, with an instance name: temp_bar

From the stage I want to remove the movieclip named "temp_bar"

main.removeChild(temp_bar) and removeChild(main.temp_bar) from stage doesn't work.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Are you getting error messages? Define "doesn't work".

Comment: ArgumentError: Error #2025: The supplied DisplayObject must be a child of the caller.

Comment: That means temp_bar was never added to the stage or the main movieclip, make sure it is added.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming temp_bar is an instance name, try using:

`main.removeChild(main.getChildByName("temp_bar"));`

---

If there only one child to main always, use:

`main.removeChildAt(0);`